# How to convert 2d image into 3d image in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gdi

how to convert a 2d image into a 3d image
like i need a function that takes the 2d image path and returns 3d image , 
any apis or application available to give this feature in asp.net or vb.nt

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific here. There's no general way to go from 2d to 3d without the images having some other specific characteristics, and even then there's no magic method in Visual Basic that'll do it. What kind of 2d pictures do you have (subject, format, etc.), and what are you trying to make the 3d version look like?

Comment: HI  i have suppose a .png file and just  it convert into a 3d image in any 3d version.

Comment: Just some .png file that you found on the web somewhere? In the general case, the image doesn't contain enough image by itself to compute a 3-dimensional scene.

Comment: I suspect what he means is, how does he output a 3D image file that contains nothing but a 2D surface with the 2D image on that surface. In other words, convert from one file format to the other, but not alter the image itself in any way.